# Exact text match on MongoDB document array in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve a single document (first) from a collection using an exact match on the MongoDB collection in Java.

The collection is as follows:

```
{ "_id": 1, "color": "red", "qty": 5, "vendor": ["Vendor A"] }
{ "_id": 2, "color": "purple", "qty": 10, "vendor": ["Vendor C", "Vendor D"] }
{ "_id": 3, "color": "blue", "qty": 8, "vendor": ["Vendor B", "Vendor A"] }
{ "_id": 4, "color": "white", "qty": 6, "vendor": ["Vendor"] }
```

I want to query and return the document by searching for "Vendor" (string: keySearch) in the vendor tags:

```
{ "_id": 4, "color": "white", "qty": 6, "vendor": ["Vendor"] }
```

But, the following code I wrote returns the first document instead:

```
Bson filter = Filters.text("\"" + keySearch + "\"");
Document doc = collection.find(filter).first();
```

I also tried the following, but this returns nothing:

```
Bson elemInArrayMatch = elemMatch("vendor", eq(keySearch));
Document doc = collection.find(elemInArrayMatch).first();
```

I want to perform an exact match on the vendor tag, i.e., when the keySearch is "Vendor" it should return (in this case) only one document, ID: 4. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can search by the exact array value match  as follow: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MHAixL5kjUv

Comment: Thanks @R2D2, do you know how to convert this code to Java? I am not able to do it in Mongo Compass as it requires Atlas.

Comment: I'm not sure how the comment about Compass is relevant, but just to clarify - Compass doesn't require Atlas. I connect to a local instance with Compass everyday

Comment: `Filters.text` is for text search not equality match, try using `eq("vendor","Vendor")`

Comment: @Joe somehow this does not work. collection.find(Filters.eq("vendor","Vendor")) returns null.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do something like:

```
private static void findExample(DBCollection collection) {
    BasicDBObject Query = new BasicDBObject();
    Query.put("vendor","Vendor");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(Query);
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
}
```

example from mongoDB java docs [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/usage-examples/find/)

Comment: I am trying to use the current API with Filters.eq() as @Joe suggested, but somehow it does not work.